# Enable WCF Tracing in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: wcf, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am trying with various SDK-based tools to interact with an on-premise instance of MS Dynamics CRM 2015. This instance is hosted by a third party provider, I have an admin account for it.

Login and normal admin operations on the web interface work as expected.

Whenever I try to access the CRM through the SDK, I get this cryptic error message: `An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party`. From this question (["An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893286/an-unsecured-or-incorrectly-secured-fault-was-received-from-the-other-party)) I expect it to be a client-server time offset, but no better evidence of it. I'd like to get any relevant logging, including the WCF logs.

How can I retrieve thos WCF logs?

Comment: Since you don't have access to the server I don't Think you can... How is the server set up? Have you tried to use the Connection examples in the SDK?

Comment: I don't know much of the server config. The errors I got come from those SDK examples.

Comment: How is the CRM set up? Is it an IFD or a standard on-prem?

Comment: I (the OP) have given up using the SDK and finished the project with the web interface only. That means the problem is solved and I can't access any information. Should I close the question?